# Microsoft Word - Can't export PDF file using applescript

Tags: ms-word, applescript, automator

I tried to convert docx to pdf and renamed the file by getting some letters from the original file name.

In Automator, I used "Get Specified Finder Items" and "Run AppleScript".

I executed and got a pop-up message in the Microsoft Word

> "Can't export file. Something went wrong, and your file can't be exported now. Please try again later."

Anyone has any ideas what's wrong? Please help me out.
Thanks.

- Microsoft Word : 16.35 (20030802)
- Automator : 2.10 (492)
- macOS : 10.15.4

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with aFile in input
        tell application "Microsoft Word"
            launch
            try
                open aFile
                tell document 1

                    set fileName to aFile as text
                    set newName to "p" & (text 14 thru 15 of fileName) & "-" & (text 11 thru 12 of fileName) & "-" & (text 8 thru 9 of fileName)

                    set pdfOutput to (newName & ".pdf")
                    save as file name pdfOutput file format format PDF


                end tell
                close document 1 saving yes
            on error
                try
                    close document 1 saving no
                end try
            end try
        end tell
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your intent, the problem is this line:

```
set fileName to aFile as text
```

which you should change to

```
set fileName to the name as text
```

I cannot be sure without further experiment and partly because it depends on exactly what your path names look like, but in the code you have

```
set fileName to aFile as text
```

which means that fileName contains the full AFS pathname of the document path + file, with ":" separators, and that expressons such as

```
text 14 thru 15 of fileName
```

are picking characters from the *path*, perhaps including ":" characters, which may be causing the problem you see, whereas I think your intent is to pick characters from the *file name*.

(Also, I have not looked at the scenario where the file name does not contain the 8 or more characters your code currently references.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I'm very new to the applescript.
I didn't know that aFile contains the full AFS path name.

I just want to get the file name which is not included document path.
My file name looks like this:
xxxxxx_YY-MM-DD_xxxx.docx

and try to rename to this:
pDD-MM-YY.pdf

(DD, MM, YY are numbers.)

I tried changing the code as your suggestion.
`set fileName to the name as text`

and also try this.
`set fileName to document name as text`

But there was no pdf file exported.
Is there something I overlook?

Comment: @Anonymademoiselle if you don’t provide a path name the .pdf will probably be saved in an unexpected folder. E.g. if your username is “username” it will probably be in /Users/username/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Documents . So have a look in there. (In Finder, hold down Alt (Option)  when you open the Go menu, then click the Library option to open the Library folder - otherwise Finder hides the Library.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your script as is, the PDF will end up in a folder like `/Users/<your_name>/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Documents/` (like @slightly-snarky commented).

Try it this way:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with aFile in input
        tell application "Finder" to set theFolder to (folder of aFile) as text -- !!!
        tell application "Microsoft Word"
            launch
            try
                open aFile
                tell document 1

                    set fileName to aFile as text
                    set loc to location of aFile
                    set newName to "p" & (text 14 thru 15 of fileName) & "-" & (text 11 thru 12 of fileName) & "-" & (text 8 thru 9 of fileName)

                    set pdfOutput to (theFolder & newName & ".pdf") -- !!!
                    save as file name pdfOutput file format format PDF


                end tell
                close document 1 saving yes
            on error
                try
                    close document 1 saving no
                end try
            end try
        end tell
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

The changes are in the lines with `-- !!!` as comments